# Naming convention for controller used to parse a page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming, convention

I want to have a page where a User can enter a URL and on the back the page will be parsed and show back some information found in the page.

I am wondering what would be a naming convention for this case, given the fact that there is no model associated with this. It is just a pure processing of a URL and show some information back.

I was thinking giving the controller the name **ParseController**, but I am also thinking about the convention of giving plural names for controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could name it `PagesController` and have an action named `parse`

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def parse
  end
end
```

And if you ever wanted to have a model, it could be called `Page`

Its just what i think. But there are many other names that you could call it.

Comment: Good. That action would be responsible for parsing, but what about the action responsible to show the form where the user can insert the URL of the page to parse?